# Does anyone know the ticker for the ftse index yahoo finance?

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

^FTSE doesn't seem to work as a ticker. I am trying to retrieve the closing price of the ftse index. The code works just fine retrieving prices for other shares/stocks, but I can't find the correct ticker for the ftse index. Anyone know it?

```
stock_tickers = "^FTSE".split(",")

data = pd.DataFrame()

dt_start = '1995-01-01'

dt_end   = '2019-01-5'

for st in stock_tickers:

    print("Loading data for %s" % st)

    df_t = wb.get_data_yahoo(st,start=dt_start, end=dt_end)

    print("Retrieved: %s" % str(df_t.shape), df_t.columns)

    data[st] = df_t['Close']
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Yahoo doesn't carry history for that index.

Comment: That's a shame. Thank you for your input.

Comment: I've managed to get historical data from Yahoo for ^FTSE for the Excel Add-in I am building. I don't know how the Python library you are using works, but it looks like it needs fixing.